# jQuery - if select option is unselected, remove an element

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a multiselect that creates an `<li>` using the text of each `:selected` option.  How would I go about removing that `<li>` if the option becomes unselected?

I'm using the code below (from here) to append the `<li>` for each `:selected` item.

```
    $('option:selected', select).each(function(index, value) {
            $('ul.multiselect-dropdown-options-'+name+'').append('<li>'+$(value).text()+'</li>');
        });
```

Comment: It seems you are building the whole list from scratch whenever an option is selected/deselected. That should already work.

Comment: FWIW, the multiselect is in a modal and the append happens on a click.  If I re-enter the modal, I can unselect the option, but it doesn't remove the `<li>` on the next click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted your code to the following:

```
$('#select').change(
    function(){
        $('#ulSelect').empty();
        $(this).find('option:selected').each(
            function(){
                $('<li />').text($(this).text()).attr('data-value',this.value).appendTo($('#ulSelect'));
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P2d9q/)

This takes care of the de-selection by, each time the `select` changes, emptying the `ul` and then appending only those elements that *are* selected into the `ul`.

The `li` elements *are*, however, given a `data-*` attribute containing a reference to the original value of the `option` from which they were taken/copied, so it should be possible to relate the `li` to the original `option` should you want to take a different approach.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Comment: That's perfect.  `.empty()` is what I was looking for.  Thanks sir!